# How to create multiple angularjs controller using for loop?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to create multiple controller on fly from json data. Is it possible to create using for loop?
I like to create dynamic widget in adf-widget-angular-dashboard and there is one controller for each widget.
my JSON data is as following:

```
[{
    "title": "Testwidget",
    "widgetTypes": ["PreVisitorsTrafficPrecGraph", "PreTotalPasserByGraph", "PreTotalVisitorsGraph", "PreNewUsersGraph", "PreReturnUsersGraph"],
    "description": "This is Description",
    "category": "customWidget",
    "controller": "newWidgetTimeSeriesGraphTypeCtrl",
    "controllerName": "newWidgetTimeSeriesGraphType",
    "templateUrl": "line-bar-chart1",
    "graphType": "line",
    "graphDetails": "TimeSeries"
  },
  {
    "title": "Testwidget1",
    "widgetTypes": ["SessionsPerHour"],
    "description": "This is Description1",
    "category": "customWidget",
    "controller": "newWidgetTimeSeriesGraphTypeCtrl2",
    "controllerName": "newTimeSeriesGraphType",
    "templateUrl": "line-bar-chart1",
    "graphType": "line",
    "graphDetails": "HourSeries"
  },
  {
    "title": "Testwidget2",
    "widgetTypes": ["PreTotalVisitorsGraph", "PreTotalPasserByGraph"],
    "description": "This is Description2",
    "category": "customWidget",
    "controller": "newWidgetTimeSeriesGraphTypeCtrl",
    "controllerName": "newWidgetTimeSeriesGraphType1",
    "templateUrl": "line-bar-chart1",
    "graphType": "line",
    "graphDetails": "CorelationSeries"
  },
  {
    "title": "Testwidget3",
    "widgetTypes": ["PreNewUsersGraph", "PreReturnUsersGraph"],
    "description": "This is Description3",
    "category": "customWidget",
    "controller": "newWidgetTimeSeriesGraphTypeCtrl",
    "controllerName": "newSeriesGraphType",
    "templateUrl": "line-bar-chart1",
    "graphType": "line",
    "graphDetails": "MultiSeries"
  },
  {
    "title": "Testwidget4",
    "widgetTypes": ["PreNewUsersGraph", "PreReturnUsersGraph"],
    "description": "This is Description4",
    "category": "customWidget",
    "controller": "newWidgetTimeSeriesGraphTypeCtrl",
    "controllerName": "SeriesGraphType",
    "templateUrl": "line-bar-chart1",
    "graphType": "line",
    "graphDetails": "OthersSeries"
  }
]
```

Comment: why not use `ng-repeat`?

Comment: I am using adf-angularjs-dashboard and I need to add widgets dynamically.